# How to map a collection fetched from Strapi through getStaticProps in a Next.js component

Tags: javascript, next.js, strapi

I am following a YouTube tutorial on how to make a simple blog using Next.js and Strapi. Below is the code for fetching post data from Strapi. It does not work because the .map function used in the Home function can only be used on arrays. I am fetching an object from Strapi. How do I get around this? And also, if you view the YouTube tutorial that I am following ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrmndNpWSJw&t=502s)), at the 30 minutes mark, you can see that the person is using the .map function even though "posts" is an object. How does that work?

```js
export default function Home({ posts }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {posts &&
        posts.map((post) => (
          <div key={post.id}>
            <p>{post.Title}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/api/posts");
  const posts = await res.json();

  return {
    props: { posts },
  };
}
```

UPDATE: I was able to find out the solution to the problem by writing the following code:

```
export default function Home({ posts }) {
  return (
    <div>    
      {posts &&
        posts.data.map((post) => (
          <div key={post.attributes.id}>
            <p>{post.attributes.Title}</p>
            <p>hello there</p>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/api/posts");
  const posts = await res.json();

  return {
    props: { posts },
  };
}
```

The JSON data that I was trying to access was under data and attributes.

Comment: I checked out the video, the response he is getting is an array of objects. Look at timestamp 29:03

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're just hitting the wrong endpoint there (depends on which version of Strapi you instantiated):

#### Strapi v3

for below v4 as illustrated in the video you're following it's `http://localhost:1337/posts`, not `http://localhost:1337/api/posts`

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/posts");
  const posts = await res.json();

  return {
    props: { posts },
  };
}
```

I guess `http://localhost:1337/api/posts` just returns an error string or object..

#### Strapi v4

If however you're using Strapi v4 then the response is wrapped in a proper JSON:API format - which means that you have a `data` object that holds the array. (see https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/rest-api.html#endpoints)

In this case you can iterate through the array on the data object

```js
    {posts &&
        posts.data.map((post) => (
          <div key={post.id}>
            <p>{post.Title}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
```

Generally, if you run into this kind of trouble check the Network tab of your browser to see what response you actually receive with the XHR request or log the result somehow to inspect the problem and determine a path forward.

Answer (score 1):

In the video tutorial [at this point](https://youtu.be/WrmndNpWSJw?t=1815) it shows an array *of objects*. `map()` iterates through each item in the array, returning the object as the variable `post`.

It is hard to answer why Strapi isn't returning an array without showing what is actually returned by `posts`. From checking the [API docs](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/rest-api.html#get-entries) it looks like the array may be under the key `data`. It also looks like if you get 1 entry, it will not be in an array (in which case you could either throw it in one yourself by sandwiching it in brackets... or just not use `map()`.

Comment: Thanks for the link! What would I use instead of the map() function?

Comment: If you only have a single post object and this is what you want, then you don't need to iterate through anything and use the object's values and keys directly (posts.title, posts.date, etc). However, it's probable (but I don't know enough about Strapi to be sure), that you will have an array as `posts.data`, which means you should continue to use `Array.map()` as in the future you will certainly have to deal with multiple posts.

Comment: I entered a couple more entries for the post data, but it still does not work.

Comment: Can you update your original question with the contents of `posts`? Try console.log(posts) before the return in your `getStaticProps()`.

Comment: I don't know why your solution wasn't working earlier, but it now works for some reason!